# indicator-datetime blinks after turning on calendar syncronization

Tags: unity, 22.04, calendar

I'm using ubuntu 22.04 with Unity deskop, and when I add a new online account and enable calendar syncronization indicator-datetime blinks, looks like it's constantly crashing and restarting itself. For now it's disabled, but are there other ways of overcoming this issue?

Comment: Being specific on your system may help, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop comes with the GNOME desktop, so did you add the Unity desktop to your system? remove the default GNOME desktop & then add Unity 7 etc... How you switched to Unity desktop may relate.  Did you look in `/var/crash` for any crash files?  is it crashing/restarting (system logs or contents in `/var/crash` should provide proof of that I'd expect)

Comment: Well, I installed unity desktop to my system using command:
`sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop` I did not see `/var/crash` though. 
The problem persisted whether I had gnome installed or not, I installed it on top of regular ubuntu 22.04 desktop

Comment: I was able to solve it, though it's rather a workaround. I disabled calendar syncronization in online accounts and it went away.